# How to check if image is hotlinkable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hotlinking

Using Ruby, I want to check an image to see if it's hotlinkable. The code I have works in many cases, but sometimes it doesn't.

Code:

```
  class Hotlinkable

    def self.is_hotlinkable? url
    return if url.blank?
        begin
            res = get_response_with_redirect URI.parse(url)
            res.code == '200'
        rescue => e
      puts e.inspect
            false
        end
    end

    def self.get_response_with_redirect(uri)
    r = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    if r.code == "301"
      r = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(r.header['location']))
    end
    r
    end

  end
```

For example, this image return a 403 in when run through the code above:
https://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2019/08/IMG_20190808_104849.jpg

But when I put it in an image tag it loads just fine.

Any idea why the above code is returning a 403?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things going on here.
First, you don't provide any request headers. This way the server can tell the request doesn't come from browser and responds with 403.
Adding any User-Agent resolves the issue. For best results, however, inspect the headers sent by a browser and copy all of them.

The next one is dealing with SSL. You need to tell Net::HTTP to use SSL for https request.

Here is an updated script for getting the response:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2019/08/IMG_20190808_104849.jpg")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
if uri.scheme == 'https'
  http.use_ssl = true 
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
end
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request["User-Agent"] = "curl/7.58.0"

response = http.request(request)
```